# Is there a way to encode integer values that are larger than 32 bits using bs-json?

Tags: json, reason, bs-json

I've been using strings to represent decoded JSON integers larger than 32 bits.  It seems the `string_of_int` is capable of dealing with large integer inputs.  So a decoder, written (in the Json.Decode namespace):

```
id: json |> field("id", int) |> string_of_int,  /* 'id' is string */
```

is succefully dealing with integers of at least 37 bits.

Encoding, on the other hand, is proving troublesome for me.  The remote server won't accept a string representation, and is expecting an int64.  Is it possible to make `bs-json` support the `int64` type?  I was hoping something like this could be made to work:

```
type myData = { id: int64 };

let encodeMyData = (data:myData) => Json.Encode.(object_([("id", int64(myData.id)]))
```

Having to roll my own encoder is not nearly as formidable as a decoder, but ... I'd rather not.

Comment: @glennsl Would it be "safe" to just add `external int64 : int64 -> Js.Json.t = "%identity"` to the encoder files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say exactly what problem you have with encoding. The `int` encoder does literally nothing except change the type, trusting that the `int` value is actually valid. So I would assume it's the `int_of_string` operation that causes problems. But that begs the question, if you can successfully decode it as an `int`, why are you then converting it to a `string`?

The underlying problem here is that JavaScript doesn't have 64 bit integers. The [max safe integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) is 2<sup>53</sup> - 1. JavaScript doesn't actually have integers at all, only `float`s, which can represent a certain range of integers, but can't efficiently do integer arithmetic unless they're converted to either 32-bit or 64-bit `int`s. And so for whatever reason, probably consistent overflow handling, it was decided in the [EcmaScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-262_5th_edition_december_2009.pdf) that binary bitwise operations should operate on 32-bit integers. And so that opened the possibility for an internal 32-bit representation, a notation for creating 32-bit integers, and the possibility of optimized integer arithmetic on those.

So to your question:

> Would it be "safe" to just add external int64 : int64 -> Js.Json.t = "%identity" to the encoder files?

No, because there's no 64-bit integer representation in JavaScript, `int64` values are represented as an array of two `Number`s I believe, but is also an internal implementation detail that's subject to change. Just casting it to `Js.Json.t` will not yield the result you expect.

**So what *can* you do then**?

I would recommend using `float`. In most respects this will behave exactly like JavaScript numbers, giving you access to its full range.

Alternatively you can use [`nativeint`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Nativeint.html), which should behave like `float`s except for division, where the result is truncated to a 32-bit integer.

Lastly, you could also implement your own `int_of_string` to create an `int` that is technically out of range by using a couple of lightweight JavaScript functions directly, though I wouldn't really recommend doing this:

```
let bad_int_of_string = str => 
  str |> Js.Float.fromString |> Js.Math.floor_int;
```

Comment: That was very informative, thank you.  I was aware that in JS, int was limited to the significant of a IEEE-754 double, and it seems that `string_of_int` handles the 53 (ish) bits.  What wasn't understood was the `int` in Re seems to be limited to 32bits - at least that's as far as my investigation got.  I'll try your suggestions.  Again,  thank you.

Comment: `int` itself isn't limited to 32 bits. It's just an ordinary JavaScript `Number` underneath, effectively a `float`. But some `int` __operations__ are limited to 32-bits, probably because they're optimized for integer arithmetic.

Comment: `nativeint` + the OCaml documentation allowed me to _store_ an int of the 37 bits I required, but serializing is proving difficult during compile:
`Json.Encode.(object_([("id", int(myData.id)),]))`
The compiler is asking for a `nativeint()` method.  
Using the `int64` hack I suggested, unfortunately did - as you predicted - serialize the number into an array of two.  Are you able to suggest a strategy for the final step of serializing?

Comment: BTW: if you try to assign a greater than 32 bit number to an `int` type, the value is truncated to 32 bits in JS code.

Comment: For encoding a `nativeint` you'd have to add an encoder like you suggested for `int64`. It won't work for `int64` as that has a different representation, but it should work for `nativeint`. I'd recommend just using `float` instead though. You can hide the implementation behind an abstract type if you want, and provide just the operations you need for that.

Comment: Ahh ... thank you so much.  Using float (which, obviously I didn't expect) worked.  Your library is made all the better by your informative and timely answers.

Comment: Happy to help!!